# explain the output of this code (when using continuous assignment and change the variable that will be used in the same statement)

Tags: java, buffer

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 0;
        int[] b = new int[5];
        int c = 3;
        b[a] = a = 3;//a is covered with 3, why the entry assigned with 3 is b[0] instead of b[3]
        System.err.println(b[0]);
        System.err.println(b[3]);
        System.err.println(b[a]);
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
3
0
0
```

I guess the reason may be fifth like Intermediate variable buffer, but i'm still not quite sure about how the statement `b[a] = a = 3;` works.

Comment: Have you tried printing out `a` and seeing what if it has changed?

Comment: of course i have, a is changed to 3 @3kings

Comment: left to right. thats how you do it.

Comment: int a = b = c = d is equals to int a = (b = (c = d)) @3kings